# Does a function that receives a function as a parameter can still be considered a pure function?

Tags: javascript

is addVat a pure function?

```
function addVat(country, getVat, amount)
{
   if(amount > 0) {
     return amount + getVat(country)*amount
   }
   
   return amount
}
```

Having a function as a parameter - getVat - makes addVat automatically impure?

Depending on the implementation of getVat, we could introduce any side effects... getVat could return a random value making the result of addVat unpredictable.

```
const getVat = ()=> Math.random()
addVat('UK',getVat, 20)
```

Case of producing external side-effects...

```
const getVat = ()=> {
  updateDbWithVatUsed(0.2)
  return 0.2
}
addVat('UK',getVat, 20)
```

By other hand, the unit testing is feasible as side effects or data variability is outside of the pure function and we can stub this to make testing totally predictable.

```
const getUKVat = ()=> 0.2
assert.equal(addVat('UK',getUkVat, 20), 24)
```

My doubts come from... is purity defined as what the function does excluding anything what happens to an external call that has been passed as a parameter?

Otherwise, as high order function is a theme for Functional programming... does it not make it impossible to classify a function as pure just by itself without considering invocation considerations.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of [Is a function immediately impure if it takes a function as a parameter?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/300682/is-a-function-immediately-impure-if-it-takes-a-function-as-a-parameter) on [softwareengineering.SE]

Comment: "*is purity defined as what the function does excluding anything else*" - yes. Remember that purity and referential transparency are only abstractions that help us to reason about code, so you should go for the assumption that makes them more useful. The abstractions always do break down at some level, be it about [identity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38706029/1048572) or [side effects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52680698/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi Being Javascript a non functional language I like the pragmatism you have explained. I appreciate if you take a look to the functional architecture question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69700611/12625403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on `getVat()`. If `getVat()` is pure `addVat()` is pure too :)

Comment: But `getVat` is a parameter, and could be anything. So do you mean we cannot say anything about `addVat` unless looking at specific calls?

Comment: I think yes because this specific calls depends on getVat() implementation.
If const getVat = ()=> Math.random() returns 10 in my opinion addVat() is pure because it returns the same value for the same sets of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript language does not enforce purity, and hence it's impossible to guarantee purity of a function which invokes functions passed as arguments. This [thread](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/300682/is-a-function-immediately-impure-if-it-takes-a-function-as-a-parameter?newreg=5941893065dc4985aecf746deb531a00) might help.